# Best approach to typedef the result of a mpl evaluation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, type-traits

I am wondering what are the pro/cons of the various ways to present the result of an mpl evaluation.

Take this one as an example for the discussion:

```
namespace bt = boost;
namespace bm = bt::mpl;

namespace v0 {
  template<class C>
  struct check
  {
     template<class D>
     struct is_same : bt::is_same<C,D> {};
  };
} // namespace v0

namespace v1 {
  template<class C>
  struct check
  {
     template<class D>
     using is_same = bt::is_same<C,D>;
  };
} // namespace v1

namespace v2 {
  template<class C>
  struct check
  {
     template<class D>
     using is_same = bm::bool_< bt::is_same<C,D>::value >;
  };
} // namespace v2
```

So what would be the prefered approach in between the three versions, or even what would be your other way to do it? And of course, why...

On my side I would go for v2, in order to have a consistent type evaluation for `check::is_same` to `bm::bool_` that can directly be used in template specializations.
But boost is not doing that and just relies on the resulting type properties (static constants and types), so I am certainly missing something...

Comment: You are over-thinking it. Just use `boost::mpl::is_same` directly.

Comment: Not really an answer but just to share some of my frustration. MSVC 2013 update 4 is really badly supporting type aliases; using them results in plenty of C1001 compiler crashes... So for now, I would say avoid any using construct to the benefit of the old typedef way. That is a shame that in 2015 MSVC still not supports C++11 features :(